# Display nested categories, subcategories and articles

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I got two tables:

**1. article:** 
`id, title, content, catid`

**2. categories:**
`id, title, parent`

Now I want to display all the categories in a box. The boxes should contain all subcategories (=parent) as boxes and all articles (=catid)

**e.g.**

```
Box Vegetables (Level 1)
    Box Red vegetables (Level 2)
        Tomatoes
        Beetroot
    Box Green vegetables (Level 2)
        Cucumber
    Other vegetable 1 (article)
    Other vegetable 2 (article)
Box Cars (Level 1)
    BoxRacing Cars (Level 2)
        F1 Racing Car
        Nascar Car
    Ford Fiesta (article)
    Opel Corsa (article)
```

This is my SQL and PHP attempt.

```
$categories = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM categories');
$subcategories = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM categories WHERE parent = :id');
$articles = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM articles WHERE catid = :id');

$categories->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$categories->execute();
if ($categories->rowCount()) {
    while($cat = $categories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo '<div class="list">';
        echo cat->title;
            $subcategories->bindParam(':id', $cat->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $subcategories->execute();
            if ($subcategories->rowCount()) {
                while($subcat = $subcategories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    echo '<div class="list">';
                    echo subcat->title;

                    $art->bindParam(':id', $subcat->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $art->execute();
                    if ($art->rowCount()) {
                        while($article = $art->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                            echo $article->title;
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }

            $art->bindParam(':id', $cat->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $art->execute();
            if ($art->rowCount()) {
                while($article = $art->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    echo $article->title;
                }
            }

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Can I do that more efficient? Do I really need that much SQL-Statements and while-loops?

Answer (score 0):

Code is untested, see the comments:

```
//You're fetching everything anyway, so why not do it in a single step?
$categories = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, parent FROM categories');
$articles = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content, catid FROM articles');

$categories->execute();
$articles->execute();

//Now we've got a mess, let's organize it
$categoriesById = array();
$childrenCategories = array();
$articlesByCategory = array();

while($cat = $categories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $categoriesById[$cat->id] = $cat;
    if ($cat->parent) $childrenCategories[$cat->parent] = $cat;
}
while($article = $articles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $articlesByCategory[$article->catid][] = $article;
}

//A function for printing the categories, so that we can call it recursively
function printCategory($category, $childrenCategories, $articlesByCategory) {
   echo '<div class="list">';
   echo $category->title;

    foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory) {
        printCategory($childrenCategory, array(), $articlesByCategory);
    }

    if (!empty($articlesByCategory[$category->id])) {
        $article = $articlesByCategory[$category->id];
        echo $article->title;
    } 

   echo '</div>';
}

//Print out stuff
foreach($categoriesById as $id => $category) {
    if ($category->parent) continue; //Skip subcategories
    printCategory(
        $category,
        !empty($childrenCategories[$id]) ? $childrenCategories[$id] : array(),
        $articlesByCategory
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My point is to form the data inside of database.

First of all, I believe that the `articles` without `category` can not be in described system. After making such conclusion, I have created a query to fetch data with your conditions and it implements two additional conditions:

1. There is no subcategory for some parent catefories.
2. Some articles has parent category, but not subcategory.

Here is a **monstrous** query used to catch all the described data in one place:

```
select article_id, article_title, article_content, article_catid, catid, subcatid, category, subcategory
from
(select articles.id as article_id, articles.title as article_title, articles.content as article_content, articles.catid as article_catid, cats_n_subs.catid, null as subcatid, cats_n_subs.category, null as subcategory
from
(select categories.id as catid,subcategories.id as subcatid, categories.title as category, subcategories.title as subcategory
from
 (select * from
 categories
 where parent is null) as categories
 left join
 (select id, title, parent from categories
  where parent is not null
   union all
  select null, null, null) as subcategories
 on subcategories.parent = categories.id or subcategories.id is null
group by categories.id, subcategories.id, categories.title, subcategories.title
) as cats_n_subs
 left join
articles
 on 
articles.catid = cats_n_subs.catid
group by articles.id, articles.title, articles.content, articles.catid, cats_n_subs.catid,cats_n_subs.category

union all

select articles.id as article_id, articles.title as article_title, articles.content as article_content, articles.catid as article_catid, cats_n_subs.catid, cats_n_subs.subcatid as subcatid, cats_n_subs.category, cats_n_subs.subcategory as subcategory
from
(select categories.id as catid,subcategories.id as subcatid, categories.title as category, subcategories.title as subcategory
from
 (select * from
 categories
 where parent is null) as categories
 left join
 categories as subcategories
 on subcategories.parent = categories.id
) as cats_n_subs
 left join
articles
 on 
articles.catid = cats_n_subs.subcatid
where articles.id is not null) as cats_n_arts
order by category, case when subcategory is null then 1 else 0 end, subcategory;
```

Here you could find an [example of using this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b619/1/0)

Save VIEW with this query inside the database and use it as table in PHP.
For example, let's name VIEW with this query as `cats_n_arts`.

Next step is to prepare and use data inside PHP:

```
<?php
  $cats_n_arts = $db->prepare('SELECT article_id, article_title, article_content, article_catid, catid, subcatid, category, subcategory FROM cats_n_arts');
  $cats_n_arts->execute();
  $parent = 0;
  $subcat = -1;
  // use one WHILE cycle and several IF's to run through all the data rows:
  while($row = $cats_n_arts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    if ($row->catid != $parent) {
      if ($parent > 0) { 
        if ($subcat > -1){
          echo ' </div>';       
          $subcat = -1;
        }
        echo '</div>';
      }
     echo '<div class="list">';
     echo $row->category;
     $parent = $row->catid;
    }
    if ($row->subcatid) {
      if ($subcat > -1){
       echo ' </div>';
      }
      if ($subcat != $row->subcatid) {
        echo ' <div class="list">';
        echo $row->subcategory;
        $subcat = $row->subcatid;
      }
    } else {
      if ($subcat > 0){
        echo ' </div>';
      }
      if ($subcat != 0){
        echo ' <div class="list">';
        echo ' OTHER ';
        $subcat = 0;
      }
    }
    if ($row->article_id) {
      echo $row->article_title;
    }
  }
?>
```

Unfortunatelly, I have no possibility to test this code, but it should work fine.